# Cannot get response from github server

Tags: github, poco-libraries

I'm using POCO library to establish communication between my app and github in order to use its API, and unfortunately after sending (successfully) very basic request I'm not getting any response:

```
    URI uri("https://api.github.com/zen");
    std::string path(uri.getPathAndQuery());

    HTTPClientSession client(uri.getHost(),uri.getPort());

    HTTPRequest req(HTTPRequest::HTTP_GET, path, HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);

    client.sendRequest(req);
    HTTPResponse res;
    client.receiveResponse(res);//this throws error "Poco::Net::NoMessageException"
```

I've checked this URI and after pasting it into browser I'm getting correct response, that is, random "wisdom" from github server.
Does anyone has any idea how to fix my code so it actually gets the response?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to connect to a secure server using insecure protocol. Use [HTTPSClientSession](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.HTTPSClientSession.html).